# onClick not working In OnCreate

Tags: android, button, onclick

So I have a 2 buttons in a layout

like so:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:onClick="onClick">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Edit Spot" />
<Button android:id="@+id/btnGo" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Google Spot"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the onCreate for the activity for this I have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_spot);

    // save button
    ButtonEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
    ButtonGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    ButtonEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });

    // Go button click event
    ButtonGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go button pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

But for some reason when I tap the buttons nothing happens. I've looked around at others asking the question and tried those but still nothing. Can someone please help me figure out why it isn't working?

Thank you,
Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `onClick` properties in the `Button`'s definition, not in the `LinearLayout`.

Even if you want to reuse the same method called `onClick` you can set a tag for each button, and do a `switch` for each tag. For instance:

In your layout:

```
android:tag="1"
```

In your code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  String tag = (String) v.getTag();

  switch (Integer.parseInt(tag)) {
    case 1:  // First button
      ... 
      break;

    case 2:  // Second button
      ...
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I put the onClick Properties of both the buttons but now it crashes saying:
01-16 13:24:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15625): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.example.androidhive.ViewSpotActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnEdit'

Comment: You have to put your `onClick` method outside the `onCreate` method but inside your activity to get it working.

Comment: Btw... I don't know why was my answer downvoted, it doesn't do any bad practice (AFAIK) and it works.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I mean you did help me. Sorry you got downvoted but thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem, I didn't mean it was you, I was just saying. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onClick` from your `LinearLayout`.  Right now you have nested `onClickListeners`.  The LinearLayout is intercepting the event and likely not passing it down.

edit: somebody is blindly downvoting all these answers for some reason.  Post a comment explaining why this is wrong.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because I'm of the same opinion than you about downvoting blindly and your answer is correct.

Comment: I am afraid, someone has down-voted my answer too -.-

Comment: I was not blindly downvotimg.  Salman Ayub's answer is wrong because 1) the problem was in onClick of LinearLayout. It is useless. 2) The buttons are clickable:true by default plus you've made a typo there. NKN's approach is kinda bad with tags. It's better to use id's.

Comment: @DoctororDrive What is wrong with mine then?  Buttons are clickable by default, but if the parent is also clickable it won't pass down the click event unless you tell it to.  For example, putting buttons inside of an EditText will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please make your `Button(s)` clickable:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:onClick="onClick">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Edit Spot"
android:clickable:true />

<Button android:id="@+id/btnGo" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Google Spot"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:clickable:true/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Also implement the `onClick()` method in your `Activity`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.view_spot);

// save button
ButtonEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
ButtonGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

// getting product details from intent
Intent i = getIntent();

// getting product id (pid) from intent
pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

// Getting complete product details in background thread
new GetProductDetails().execute();

// save button click event
ButtonEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
});

// Go button click event
ButtonGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go button pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
} 

public void onCLick(View v)
{
  //Your Implementation
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Still nothing, I tried putting android:onClick="onClick in the button properties and not in the layout and it gave me the error: 01-16 13:40:29.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17174): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.example.androidhive.ViewSpotActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnEdit'

Comment: You have not applied the answer correctly. look at the code above, you have not implemented `public void onCLick(View v)
{
  //Your Implementation
}` method in your Activity.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I mean you did help me. Sorry you got downvoted but thank you for the help.

Comment: Okay, so I'm a little confused, if you couldn't tell I'm fairly new to programming on android. What would I put for the //Your Implementation? Shouldn't the onClicks inside the onCreate be implementing what I want them to do? and Should the android:onClick="onClick" be inside layout or inside the button properties?

Comment: As you have explicitly mentioned the `onClick()` method in your `Linear layout`, then you need to implement it separately (seperately from onCreate...) method as defined in the above answer. You have used `onClick()` listeners on your buttons, which will only handle the Click events of those buttons.

Comment: In //Your Implementation, you can do what ever you want to do. Like showing a Toast, showing an AlertDialog.